# Why is VBA saying that it has found an 'ambiguous name'?

Tags: vba, excel

When compiling some code (declarations shown below) I get the error message 'Compile Error: Ambiguous name detected. SixTables'.  I have looked here and elsewhere but cannot find anything that matches my problem.  What appear to be the most common causes of this error, declaring two variables with identical names or giving the same name to a function and the sub that it is called from, do not apply.  And yes, I know I could just change the name to something the system was happy with, but (1) I wouldn't learn what I'm doing wrong, and (2) I chose that name for a reason - it fits its purpose exactly :-)

```
Option Explicit

Dim ArmOfService As Byte
Dim CharacterNumber As Long
Dim CurrentTerm As Byte
Dim DecorationRollMade As Byte
Dim DecorationRollNeeded As Byte
Dim DiceSize As Byte
Dim GenAssignment
Dim GenAssignmentSwitchInt As Byte
Dim GenAssignmentSwitchOff As Byte
Dim iLoopControl
Dim jLoopControl
Dim kLoopControl
Dim LineIncrement As Integer
Dim lLoopControl
Dim Merc(100)
Dim NoOfDice As Byte
Dim OfficerPromotion(63 To 78) As Byte
Dim PromotionRollMade As Byte
Dim PromotionRollNeeded As Byte
Dim Roll As Byte
Dim SkillColumn
Dim SixTables
Dim SpecAssignmentSwitchEnd As Byte
Dim SurvivalRollMade As Byte
Dim SurvivalRollNeeded As Byte
Dim TechLevel As Byte
Dim Temp As Integer
Dim Term As Byte
Dim TestCount
Dim UnitAssignment
Dim WhichTable
Dim Year As Byte
```

EDIT: I'm so embarrassed that I can hardly bring myself to explain what the problem was.  I knew I hadn't duplicated a name, since I was only using it once - as a function!  Thanks all for your help, I'm now going to go and hide my face in shame...

Comment: I assume that changing the name does solve the problem per your post?

Comment: Do you have a code module with that name?

Comment: Clearly, from the code youve supplied we can easily tell there is no problem. You need to provide more code and possibly all combinations ie. module names, sub names, function names etc. Scan through your code with CTRL + F and search for `SixTables`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From MSDN :

1. More than one object in the same scope may have elements with the
   same name.

> Module-level identifiers and project-level identifiers (module names
>   and referenced project names) may be reused in a procedure, although
>   it makes programs harder to maintain and debug. However, if you want
>   to refer to both items in the same procedure, the item having wider
>   scope must be qualified. For example, if MyID is declared at the
>   module level of MyModule , and then a procedure-levelvariable is
>   declared with the same name in the module, references to the
>   module-level variable must be appropriately qualified:

```
Dim MyID As String 
Sub MySub 
MyModule.MyID = "This is module-level variable" 
Dim MyID As String 
MyID = "This is the procedure-level variable" 
Debug.Print MyID 
Debug.Print MyModule.MyID 
End Sub
```

1. An identifier declared at module-level conflicts with a procedure name.

> For example, this error occurs if the variable MyID is declared at
>   module level, and then a procedure is defined with the same name:

```
Public MyID 
Sub MyID 
. . . 
End Sub
```

Comment: Keiran. But I don't have anything else with the same name.

Comment: Can you duplicate the problem with a new project?

Answer (score 5):

Having had this issue many times, and not fully understanding why, I think there is an important fact that I have tested, and someone can confirm.  It may be obvious to professional programmers, but I place this here for those that seek these answers on discussions, who are usually not professional programmers.

A variable declared within a sub() is not "declared" (memory assigned) until that sub() is executed. And when the execution of that sub() is complete, the memory is released.  Until now, I thought Public variables acted in similar way; available to any module that used it, --BUT only existing as long as the module where they were declared was still executing.

However, for any Public variable who's declaration line is in any module in the workbook, that variable is declared and available at the execution of any module within the workbook, **even if the module where the Public declaration exists is never called or executed**.

Therefore, if you have a Public variable declaration in one module, and then again in a separate module that you plan to run independent of the first, Excel still sees 2 declarations for the same variable, and thus it is ambiguous.

To prove it, you can create a blank module within a workbook project, and add absolutely nothing except two Public declaration lines,

---

Public VariableX as String

Public VariableY as Integer

---

and those variables will be declared and available throughout the project, for any sub() executed. This fact is also probably the reason for the tip about minimizing the use of public variables.

Again, this may have been kindergarten level information for professional programmers, but most on this are not pros, and have to learn these lessons the hard way, or through discussion boards like this.  I hope this helps someone.

Comment: 2 years later, this solution really helped me. Thanks for the time on this response.